# How to get the start or end date of the last execution of a Spring Batch job that has a completed status?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am writing a Spring Batch process (Spring boot 2.x.x). The job selects some rows from a table based on the last update date -

```
(select * from tablename where last_upd_dt >= :lastruntime).
```

The :lastruntime is the date of the last (successfully) completed run of the job. I am trying to grab this date from the beforeJob method in the Listener class using JobListener/JobExecutionListener.

Is there a way to leverage the classes Spring Batch framework offers? Else I will have to write and retrieve this info from another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use the JobExplorer API.

```
private Date fetchPreviousJobCompletetionDate() {
    Date previousJobCompleteDate = null;
    try {
        Integer jobInstanceCount = jobExplorer.getJobInstanceCount("myjob");
        List<JobInstance> jobInstances = jobExplorer.getJobInstances("myjob", 0, jobInstanceCount);
        List<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobInstances.stream().map(jobExplorer::getJobExecutions)
                .flatMap(List<JobExecution>::stream)
                .filter(param -> param.getExitStatus().equals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(jobExecutions)) {
            Optional<JobExecution> jobExecutionOptional = jobExecutions.stream().sorted((JobExecution execution1, JobExecution execution2) -> execution2.getStartTime()
                    .compareTo(execution1.getStartTime())).findFirst();
            if (jobExecutionOptional.isPresent()) {
                previousJobCompleteDate = jobExecutionOptional.get().getStartTime();
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchJobException exception) {
        log.error("Exception occurred {}", exception.getMessage());
    }
    return previousJobCompleteDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [JobExplorer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html) API. It allows you to get the job executions of your job instance. Once you get that, you can filter the result as needed and get the start/end date from the `JobExecution` object.